A set is closed iff its intersection with every set in an open covering is closed
I am reading the answer in the post Continuity of Rational Maps in Zariski Topology, where the answerer mentioned the following lemma (sounds like an elementary fact but I fail to prove it):

Lemma: Let $S\subseteq X$ and $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an open covering of $X$, then $S$ is closed in $X$ iff $S\cap U_i$ is closed in each $U_i$.

My attempt: When $S\cap U_i$ is closed in $U_i$, we get:
$$ S=\bigcup_{i\in I} (S_i\cap U_i)$$
where $S_i$ is closed in $X$. But how to proceed?
Any hints or references are welcomed. Thanks!

Hint: Try to use nets

Suppose that $S \cap U_i$ is closed in $U_i$ for every $i$. Equivalently, $U_i \setminus S$ is open in $U_i$ and in particular open in $X$. Then, $X \setminus S = \bigcup_{i} (U_i \setminus S)$ is open, so $S$ is closed in $X$.
A good intuition is to think about convergence. A convergent sequence eventually should be a local phenomenon, i.e. eventually concentrated in some $U_i$, and here we can check closeness. It's probably a good exercise to make this intuition precise leading to another proof.

Thank you! An interesting intuition :)
